recibir valores de un formulario usando django
Buenas estoy aprendiendo django y tengo el siguiente problema y mas que he tratado no logro dar con la solucion a ver si me pueden ayudar. Quiero poder seleccionar elementos desde el frontend y asignarle a cada elemento una cantidad para crear un objecto que se guarde en la base de datos donde queda almacenado todos los elementos, en este caso alimentos con sus respectivas cantidades, es como una especie de clase dieta pero que la nombre Gramaje ya que mas adelante defino una clase Dieta con mas parametros, actualmente cuando intento pasar los valores cantidad al backend me dice que no es posible iterar elementos tipo none pero cuando inspecciono la pagina web me aparece que se estan enviando valores para cantidad, en de hecho se estan enviando una gran cantidad ya que me envia 600 y pico de valores tan solo los que rellene con un valor en especifico y los demas sin ningun valor ya que me crea para cada alimento un input.
models:
class Alimentos(models.Model):

nombre= models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
#especie = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
calorias= models.FloatField(default=0)
proteinas= models.FloatField(default=0)
carbohidratos= models.FloatField(default=0)
grasas= models.FloatField(default=0)
def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Gramaje(models.Model):
"""
 alimentos=models.ForeignKey(
    Alimentos, related_name="gramaje", on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True
) 
"""
alimentos=models.ManyToManyField(Alimentos) 

cantidad=models.FloatField(default=0)

views:
def mostrar_alimentos(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Crear_gramaje(request.POST)
    form2= Cantidad_gramaje(request.POST)
    print(form2)
    if form.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        print("entrando al if")
        
        alimentos_seleccionados = form.cleaned_data['alimentos']
        cantidad = form2.cleaned_data['cantidad']
        print(alimentos_seleccionados)
        print(cantidad)

        for alimento, cantidad in zip(alimentos_seleccionados, cantidad):
            Gramaje.objects.create(alimento=alimento, cantidad=cantidad)
        #for alimento in alimentos_seleccionados:
            #gramaje= Gramaje(alimentos=alimento,cantidad=cantidad)
            #gramaje.save()
            #Gramaje.objects.create(alimentos=request.POST['alimentos'], cantidad=request.POST['cantidad'])
            #Gramaje.objects.create(alimentos=alimento, cantidad=cantidad)
    else:
        
        print(form.errors)
        return render(request, 'alimentos.html', {'alimentos': Crear_gramaje(), 'cantidad': Cantidad_gramaje()})
else:
    return render(request, 'alimentos.html', {'alimentos': Crear_gramaje(), 'cantidad': Cantidad_gramaje()})

forms:
class Crear_gramaje(forms.Form):
alimentos = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    queryset=Alimentos.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)


class Cantidad_gramaje(forms.Form):
cantidad = forms.FloatField(label="cantidad", widget=forms.NumberInput(
    attrs={'class': 'input'}), required=False)

html:
<title>Seleccionar alimentos y cantidades</title>
<h1>Bienvenido a Django</h1>
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for alimento in alimentos.alimentos %}
    <ul>
        <li>
            {{ alimento }}
            {{ cantidad }}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit">Guardar alimentos seleccionados</button>

</form> 



